# How to dynamically query same column names from multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

My database has multiple tables that share a naming convention and the same core field names.  For example, `Billing_Detail_Parts` and `Billing_Detail_Labor`.  I want to be able to do a sum query against the price field in these tables.  We do periodically add new tables though so I want to do something like `SELECT SUM(PRICE) FROM Billing_Detail_*` and not hard code the table names.  Is there a way to accomplish this without doing it as a function?

Comment: Adding tables all the time is not a good sign. What comes after `Billing_Detail_` for instance?

Comment: Considering you are using this convention of using `PRICE` and you dont use priice for anything else in this database you can write query which generates you a query which will get all the tables containing the column `PRICE` and join them together or whatever you want to do with them.

Comment: We do not add new tables all the time but perhaps once or twice a year.  There is no consistency to what comes after Billing_Detail_ as it's name is based upon the new data.

Comment: If you are only adding tables once or twice a year, I would suggest that the best way is to maintain a view that combines the core columns of these tables, since you have to add the table anyway, it is probably not much more hassle to alter the view at the same time. You can then just sum from this view.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a sensible approach.  I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the next piece of code, maybe performance of this one is not the best but it must help you to get desire result:

```
declare @tbl_name nvarchar(max), 
        @exec_str nvarchar(max), 
        @parm_definition nvarchar(max), 
        @like nvarchar(max), 
        @select_col nvarchar(max)
declare @sum float, 
        @sum_out float
declare @cnt int, 
        @i int
set @parm_definition = N'@sumOUT float OUTPUT'
set @select_col = 'PRICE'
set @like = 'Billing_Detail_%'
set @tbl_name = ''
set @exec_str = ''
set @cnt = (select count(table_name) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_NAME like @like)
set @sum = 0
set @i = 1

while @i <= @cnt
begin
    set @tbl_name = (select TABLE_NAME 
                     from (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by TABLE_NAME) cnt, TABLE_NAME 
                           from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                           where TABLE_NAME like @like) t 
                     where t.cnt = @i)
    set @exec_str = N'select @sumOUT = sum(' + @select_col + ') from ' + @tbl_name
    execute sp_executesql @exec_str, 
                          @parm_definition, 
                          @sumOUT = @sum_out OUTPUT
    set @sum = @sum + isnull(@sum_out, 0)
    set @i = @i + 1
end
select @sum price
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach to this problem is a view. Every time you add a new table that should be included in this sum, then you just alter the view to include it. We have a build process that alters our views automatically and we do something very similar to this.

Once you have the view setup, then you can just use the view as a normal table and sum/sort/even update/delete (if you choose). If the view is not performing well, then you can look into indexed views.

```
CREATE VIEW vwNewTable 
AS
SELECT billing_detail_parts, billing_detail_labor
FROM tableA
UNION ALL
SELECT billing_detail_parts, billing_detail_labor;


ALTER VIEW vwNewTable
AS 
SELECT billing_detail_parts, billing_detail_labor
FROM tableA
UNION ALL
SELECT billing_detail_parts, billing_detail_labor
UNION ALL 
SELECT billing_detail_parts, billing_detail_labor;
```